# Change order of list items using drag and drop

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, drag-and-drop

I have used the following html and ts for drag and drop list items from one div to another div.

Html:

```
<div class="listArea">
   <h4> Drag and Drop list in Green Area: </h4>
   <ul class="unstyle">
      <li id="drag1" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
          i am list 1
      </li>
      <li id="drag2" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
          i am list 2 
      </li>
      <li id="drag3" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
          i am list 3
      </li>
      <li id="drag4" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
          i am list 4
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="buildArea" id="div1" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)">
   <h4> Drop Here </h4> 
</div>
```

And Typescript contains the following:

```
  allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
  }
```

Its from Html5 drag and drop, and i am able to drag and drop the list items from the div with class listArea to the div with class buildArea.

After dropped the list items user may change the order of the list items that was dropped in buildArea div.

For eg, the given order I am list 1,2,3,4,5 may change to any order like 2,4,5,3,1 or anything user wants.

As of now i have used only angular and typescript and no third party plugin was added and i am also need the result **without any third party or jquery.**

I have also have look around for this but unable to get a correct solution and hence kindly help me to achieve the change of order in dropped list.

The **stackblitz** link was, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyimor

Comment: You may bind an array to the target list. Whenever user drops an new item in, you can sort the array to any order you want.

Comment: you want all elements in order?

Comment: @UnluckyAj, If the user drops the list, it is getting appended one by one at last of list, and if suppose user dropped the order in wrong way, the he can change the order he wants.. Like interchanging of list items..

Comment: @wannadream, Can you kindly provide a solution way of doing it as i am new with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In your drop area, bind list items to an array.

```
<div class="buildArea" id="div1" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)">
    <h4> Drop Here </h4>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of targetItems [id]="item.id">{{item.text}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In component class:

```
targetItems: Array<TargetItem> = [];
....
drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    let text = document.getElementById(id).innerText;
    this.targetItems.push({id: id, text: text});
    this.targetItems.sort((a, b) => {
        // Implement your own sorting logic
        // e.g., return a.id - b.id;
    });
}
```

Define an interface for target item:

```
interface TargetItem {
    text: string;
    id: number;
}
```

Comment: It showing the following error,
 Argument of type '(a: TargetItem, b: TargetItem) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: TargetItem, b: TargetItem) => number'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: Check the API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @wanadream, I have implemented your code but its showing the error, You could able to see the edited code, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyimor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: sort function needs a return value of number. You can do your own comparison here, and return 1, 0, and -1. You can try 'return a.id - b.id;', change id from type string to number.

Comment: We can use *ngFor in Angular and using array will helpful. This is a updated link
https://angular-1vdjjg.stackblitz.io
I hope it may help you